# Creating a list of all functions from .py file and run random of them

Tags: python, list, function

I want to create a list of all functions in .py file and then use these functions randomly.
I've already created some list using dir(), but cannot run.

file with functions file.py:

```
def f1:
   # some code
def f2:
   # some code
def f3:
   # some code
```

another script:

```
functions = dir(file)
random.choice(functions)()
```

It shows this error

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax to call random function from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465455/syntax-to-call-random-function-from-a-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing a function randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150561/choosing-a-function-randomly)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the functions in `file1.py` contain only functions with either no arguments or functions with only default value arguments, then

if `file1.py` is

```
def f1():
    print ("f1")

def f2():
    print ("f2")

def f3():
    print ("f3")

def f4(i=0):
    print ("f4")
```

Another script will be:

```
import file1
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import random

functions_list = [o for o in getmembers(file1) if isfunction(o[1])]
random.shuffle(functions_list)

for f in functions_list:
    f[1]()
```