# Choosing a function randomly and calling it with the appropriate attributes in Python

Tags: python, function, random

The answers to [Choosing a function randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150561/choosing-a-function-randomly) tell us how to pick and call a random function from a list using `random.choice`.

But what if the functions in the list take different attributes? How do we call the function with the appropriate attributes?

Example:

```
from random import choice

def fun_1():
    ...
def fun_2(x: int):
    ...
def fun_3(y: bool):
    ...

my_integer = 8
my_boolean = True

random_function_selector = [fun_1, fun_2, fun_3]

print(choice(random_function_selector)(???))
```

The function `fun_1` takes no attributes. Whenever `fun_2` is selected, I want to call it with `my_integer`, and whenever `fun_3` is selected, I want to call it with `my_boolean`.

What do I put in the brackets in the last line?

Do I have to rely on `if` statements to check what random function was selected, and choose the appropriate attribute based on that? Or is there a shortcut?

Comment: Please update your question with sample output.

Comment: Yes, you need to check which function was selected in order to know what the appropriate number and types of arguments the function expects. The exception is if all possible functions have the same signature, in which case you don't need to know which one is being called, as the same arguments would be suitable for all of them.

Comment: @chepner That is unfortunate, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: One alternative is to select not just a function, but a tuple consisting of a function and a suitable set of arguments, e.g., `random_function_selector = [(fun_1,), (fun_2, my_integer), (fun_3, my_boolean)]`. Then you can say `f, *args = choice(random_function_selector); print(f(*args))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the desired arguments with the function in the list of choices.

```
from random import choice

def fun_1():
    ...
def fun_2(x: int):
    ...
def fun_3(y: bool):
    ...

my_integer = 8
my_boolean = True

random_function_selector = [(fun_1,) (fun_2, my_integer) (fun_3, my_boolean)]
f, *args = choice(random_function_selector)
print(f(*args))
```

Or, you can define a list of 0-argument function wrappers that make various calls.

```
from functools import partial


random_function_selector = [partial(fun_1), partial(fun_2, my_integer), partial(func_3, my_boolean)]
print(choice(random_function_selector)())
```